# Mojave Stacks feature: More specificity for grouping

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

I am trying to use Mojave's new Stacks feature that can group files on the desktop.  I have it set to group by "Kind". It created a stack called "Documents". But the contents are very heterogeneous: this stack absorbs everything from Markdown documents through Mathematica notebooks to MS Word files.

I would much rather have these types separated. Is this possible?

For my use case, it would be sufficient to make the system consider Mathematica notebooks *not* to be "documents" (and let it mix the rest of the types).